# Add Sections or Groups to MWPhotoBrowser

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mwphotobrowser

Is there anyway to add sections or groups to MWPhotoBrowser?

Let's say I want to pull up a big list of photos for venues in my area. I would want the photo browser to then be grouped and have a title for the given venue.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem?